# PHP fopen() fails on files even with wide-open permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I'm currently migrating my LAMP from my Windows Server to a VPS running Debian 6.  Most everything is working, however, one of the PHP scripts was failing to write to its configured log file.  I could not determine why, so I wrote a new, simple, contrived PHP script to test the problem.

```
<?php
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        echo exec('whoami');
        $log = fopen('/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log', 'a');
        if ($log != NULL)
        {
                fflush($log);
                fclose($log);
                $log = NULL;
        }
?>
```

However, it fails with the result:

```
www-data Warning: fopen(/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/_admin/phpwritetest.php on line 5
```

- While I would never do it normally, to help diagnose, I set `/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log` to chmod 777.
- Both the directory and the file are owned by `www-data:www-data`.
- The file was created with `touch`.

I ran `strace` to verify which process was performing the open:

```
[pid 21931] lstat("/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log", 0x7fff81677d30) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 21931] lstat("/var/log/apache2/writetest", 0x7fff81677b90) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 21931] open("/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I checked and pid 21931 was indeed one of the apache2 child processes running under `www-data`.  As you can see, I also included `echo exec('whoami');` in the script which confirmed the script was being run by `www-data`.

Other notes:

- PHP is not running in safe mode
- PHP `open_basedir` is not set
- Version info: `Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o`
- uname -a: `2.6.32-238.19.1.el5.028stab092.2 #1 SMP Thu Jul 21 19:23:22 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- This is on a VPS running under OpenVZ
- ls -l (file): `-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 Sep  8 18:13 writetest.log`
- ls -l (directory): `drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data     4096 Sep  8 18:13 writetest`
- Apache2's parent process runs under `root`, and the child processes under `www-data`
- selinux is not installed (thanks to Fabio for reminding me to mention this)
- I have restarted apache many times and rebooted the server as well

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember that in order to reach a file, ALL parent directories must be readable by www-data. You strace output seems to indicate that even *accessing* `/var/log/apache2/writetest` is failing. Make sure that www-data has permissions on the following directories:

- `/ (r-x)`
- `/var (r-x)`
- `/var/log (r-x)`
- `/var/log/apache2 (r-x)`
- `/var/log/apache2/writetest (rwx)`
- `/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log (rw-)`

Comment: That was what I had overlooked.  `/var/log/apache` was missing (r-x) while the rest were correct.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Gotta love those gut feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Does the php file doing the writing have proper permissions set? Try changing those to see if that's the issue.

Comment: Permission is `0666` as indicated by his strace

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the post? I see that the .log files are 0666 and the containing folder but not the permissions to the .php file doing the writing.

Comment: If the php file can run, shouldn't it be able to write to the file then if the other file's permissions are accurate?

Comment: I just tested a php file with file_put_contents( 'test.txt', 'data' );  when I run it from the command line as root it makes the file no issues. When I call it from the browser it does nothing. When I changed the files permissions for the .php file it worked from being called by the browser (apache).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even if I `chmod 777 writetest.php`, the problem remains.  It is owned by `root:root` which is, I believe, typical for a secure Apache setup.

Comment: Have you tried other ways to read the file? file_get_contents, file, or ( I don't know if this is do-able ) Curl it? Or if you give the .php execute permissions can you read the contents with a shell_exec command into a variable? These would just be a work-around though.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I added text to the file and tried the following: `$lines = file('/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log'); echo $lines;`, `$str = file_get_contents('/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log'); echo $str;`, and `$log = fopen('/var/log/apache2/writetest/writetest.log', 'r');`.  All three cause the same error indicated in my question.

Comment: The last thing I can think of to get that information would be    $file_contents = shell_exec( 'cat /path/to/file' );  with the .php file having execute permissions. Sorry I couldn't help more. Good luck.

Comment: Even though I really do need to get it working with the existing functions (and I'm writing, not reading anyways), I couldn't resist trying the shell_exec.  It produced no error, it just returned an empty string.  Anyways, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a SELinux issue, even if Debian doesn't ship it in the default installation your provider could have enabled it. Look for messages in `/var/log` with

```
grep -i selinux /var/log/{syslog,messages}
```

If that's the cause and you need to disable it, here are instructions: look for file `/etc/selinux/config`, here it's default content. Change `SELINUX` directive to `disabled` and reboot the system.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the excellent explanation for how to check it, but selinux is definitely not installed.  I had checked before but had forgotten to mention it in my question.  But I have seen others for whom that was the cause so hopefully your answer will help others in the future.