# PHP: creates file but can't append with (apparently) correct server permissions (LAMP)

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, permissions

I have seen many questions and answers on this topic but none seem to help my situation. My PHP code is successfully creating a new logfile, but then cannot access that file to append further info, close it, etc.

I am migrating an application from local XAMPP onto LAMP: hence problem only showing up now due to Windows/XAMPP giving no permission troubles.

I started with a default Bitnami LAMP stack, and then manually setup relevant directory permissions on server:
- my sftp user has rwx on htdocs and assorted out-of-web-root directories
- apache is running as 'daemon' so I have given read & execute permissions to relevant directories for 'daemon' as group
- in most directories I have disallowed write permissions for 'daemon'
- however for my (application generated, internal) logs I have a 'logfiles' directory which has rwx for both my user and the 'daemon' group
- 'other' is -rwx for all

When I run my application it falls over pretty much immediately.  The error logs showing fopen failed to open stream: permission denied.  However, the permissions indicate that it should have access.

When I check the file involved it has following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 962 Oct  3 10:14 20151003logfile03-10-33530.txt
```

This tells me that the file was created by Apache (i.e. by my PHP script) and that it has read and write permissions, from when I fopen() with "w"

EDIT: adding directory info:
Folder level permissions give my ftps user and daemon (group) full rwx access:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 ftpuser daemon 4096 Oct  3 10:30 logfiles
```

BUT it can't then fopen with "a"

I am assuming that this IS a file permission problem because:
a) it works fine on XAMPP
b) it states permission error in the error log

However, I can't see why it should be a problem, given directly-specified OS-level permissions ...  maybe Apache requires an .htaccess 'allow' on this directory also?

Any ideas?

---

Clarification re why I don't think CHMOD is the answer (sorry @RedAcid):
CHMOD 777 etc is simply a way to set the underlying permissions I already have. Each digit represents 3 binary chars, so 7 is 111 (i.e. read, write and execute).  As you can see above, I have read/write/execute for PHP/Apache on folder, together with read/write for file.  What I've read suggests that you need execute at directory level, but not at file level because its not trying to execute the file.

So what am I missing here? Why else might it be denying permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I found out the problem was higher level parent directory not having read/execute permissions.  Now working!  (AT LAST!)

For more detail see this previous question:

[PHP fopen() fails on files even with wide-open permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355780)

Answer (score 0):

use **chmod 666** for the file and proper **user** group permissions. folder where files are located must be writable with  **chmod 777**

Comment: Don't want 777 or 666 -- both of those give anyone significant access -> big security issues. The point is that the user permissions appear to be correct and it was able to create the file ... so why not able to append

Comment: its not security issue if you only have log files in the folder or static media.

Comment: Those logs include all kinds of stuff ... the point is that I don't want them visible to anyone else

Comment: not able to append because incorrect permissions. file is not writable you must use chmod 666

Comment: you can also do a deny from all using htaccess to protect the folder. and then chmod your files/folder