# Opencart 2.1 fopen() failed to open stream:

Tags: opencart2.x

I know there are a few posts regarding this issue, but really I don't know which folder/path to go in to fix it. Please can anyone point me to a right path and help me solve this. I really don't want to do a fresh installation.

Thank you

Comment: try to check existence of this file, its rights and then if nothing work see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355780/php-fopen-fails-on-files-even-with-wide-open-permissions

Comment: Make sure the webserver user has write privileges to the folder or file in question.  Posting the whole error would help